# Telegram instant view templates

Tags: telegram, instant-view

I am creating some Telegram instant view templates for my website. I tried to create two templates, but when I edit the date from the first template for instance, it's also changed on second template automatically.

Here is my code:

```
~version: "2.0"
$main: //div[@id="primary"]
title: $main//h1
body://div[has-class("bbWrapper")]
author: "MC-Security Articles"
description: "Nel post di oggi, parleremo dei numerosi limiti che si possono riscontrare quando si vuole aprire un sever Minecraft utilizzando hosting che offrono pannelli Multicraft (O simili)."
channel: "@MCSecurity"
published_date: "7/27/2019"
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Hi Federico, you need to add your code to let us know how to help you. Edit the question and add some information

Comment: Hello :) 
The code that I want to use for each article is the following: https://pastebin.com/HpWYJtMK

Comment: Only one template is used for all pages on one site!